# socketIO-client python callback not receiving args

Tags: python, flask, socket.io

I send a command to a flask server (files). It responds by emitting a response, as argument, a dict is provided with the requested filenames.

```
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace, BaseNamespace


def on_data_command_response(*args):
    print('on_data_command_response')
    print(len(args))
    print("-----------")


with SocketIO("192.168.1.164", 5000, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:

    socketIO.on('data command response', on_data_command_response)

    socketIO.emit('data event', {'command': 'files'}, on_data_command_response)
    socketIO.emit('data event', {'command': 'files'}, on_data_command_response)

    socketIO.wait_for_callbacks(seconds=5)
```

In flask the command is received as:

```
@socketio.on('data event')
def data_event(json, methods=['GET', 'POST']):
    print('received data command: {}'.format(json))
```

and a response is sent:

```
def emit_data_command_response(payload_json):
    socketio.emit('data command response', payload_json, callback=messageReceived)
```

The question:
It looks like the emit was receive two times. Once with args and once without for each command that I sent.

```
on_data_command_response
2
-----------
on_data_command_response
0
-----------
on_data_command_response
2
-----------
on_data_command_response
0
-----------
```

VARIATION 1:

```
socketIO.on('data command response', on_data_command_response)


socketIO.emit('data event', {'command': 'files'}, on_data_command_response)
socketIO.emit('data event', {'command': 'files'})
socketIO.emit('data event', {'command': 'files'})
socketIO.emit('data event', {'command': 'files'})
```

returns

```
on_data_command_response
2
-----------
on_data_command_response
0
-----------
on_data_command_response
2
-----------
on_data_command_response
2
-----------
on_data_command_response
2
-----------
```

but VARIATION 2 (which I thought looked the most logical):

```
socketIO.on('data command response', on_data_command_response)
socketIO.emit('data event', {'command': 'files'})
```

on_data_command_response does not even get called.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here. Any help to get callback "on_data_command_response" called once with args?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that I confused callback and emit. 
--> callback is when a server "returns" an emit command. 
--> socketIO.on.... is guiding when a server did an emit.
socketIO.wait(seconds=1) --> waits for callbacks. So, if no callback functions provided, it doesn't do anything.

https://pypi.org/project/socketIO-client/

A client:

```
import time
from socketIO_client import SocketIO, LoggingNamespace, BaseNamespace


def on_data_command_response(*args):
    if len(args) > 0:
        print(len(args))
        # print('on_data_command_response')
        # for arg in args[0]:
           # print((arg)) 
    else:
        print("no args received.")
    # return # send acknowledgement

def message_received_by_servercallback(*args):
    print("----all good----")

def on_disconnect():
    print("lode disconnect")



with SocketIO("192.168.1.164", 5000, LoggingNamespace) as socketIO:

    socketIO.on('disconnect', on_disconnect)

    socketIO.on('data command response', on_data_command_response)

    socketIO.emit('backend event', {'command': 'files'}, message_received_by_servercallback)

    socketIO.wait_for_callbacks(seconds=1)
```

with a server:

```
@socketio.on('backend event')
def backend_request(json):
    if "command" in json.keys():  
        if json["command"] == "files":
            response_json = {}
            response_json["status"] = "download files"

    payload_json = response_json
    socketio.emit('data command response', payload_json, callback=messageReceived)
    return ["received"] # will trigger the callback
```

performs as expected (client terminal):

```
2
----all good----
lode disconnect
>>>
```